# posting csv file with its name in angular 8

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-httpclient

I have a Data-Import-Module with data-import.service, data-import component, and its child components: uploader.component(with its own service defined in uploader module) save.component(button) and display-table.component (button) and table.component.

I want to upload csv file(which I imagine as table with points, Point(x;y;)), save it to the server using httpClient.post method passing with body{fileName, content-of-csv-parsed to-json or just a table}, display a table with content of uploded file.

httpClient methods are new to me and i really don't understand what for are headers and param which are third (options) argument in post method- should i put there fileName or should i put it body with Point[]? Can body have more than one parameter? Should i create File(fileName:string, points: Point[]) and put is as body?

```
export class DataImportService {

constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

baseUrl: string="api/files";

postFile(fileName:string, points: Point[] ):Observable<any>{

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl,{fileName,points} ){};
}
```

vs

```
export class DataImportService {

constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

baseUrl: string="api/files";

postFile(file:File ):Observable<File>{

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl,file ){};
}
```

These are my two conceptons, i really want to understand :

```
DataImportComponent{

constructor(private dataService: DataImportService)

saveFile(data.csv){
...
return this.dataService.dataService.post(...).subscribe(
x=>{parsed to json});

)
}
}
```